# to prove the divergency of sum f_n

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $f_n(x)=\min_{m\in\mathbb{Z}}\mid x-\frac{m}{n}\mid$ prove that if $x\not\in\mathbb{Z}$ then $\sum_{n\ge1} f_n$ is divergent.

Comment: Try contrapositive: If $\sum_{n\ge1} f_n$ is convergent then $x\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\|x\|=\min_{m\in\mathbb{Z}}|x-m|$ denote the distance from the nearest integer. Obviously, $f_n(x)=\frac1n\|nx\|$. We need an easy estimate: we have
$$\sin^2\pi x\le\sin\pi x\le\pi x$$for all positive $x$, meaning $\|x\|=x\ge\frac1\pi\sin^2\pi x$ for $x\in[0,1/2]$. By symmetry and periodicity, we have $\|x\|\ge\frac1\pi\sin^2\pi x$ for all real $x$. So
$$\sum^\infty_{n=1}f_n(x)=\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{\|nx\|}n\ge\frac1\pi\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{\sin^2\pi nx}n=\frac1{2\pi}\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{1-\cos2\pi nx}n.$$ Since the harmonic series diverges, and $\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{\cos2\pi nx}n$ converges for $x\notin\mathbb{Z},$ our series can converge only for $x\in\mathbb{Z}$ (where it's identical $0$).